# smart table with angularjs 1.5 component

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I can see smart-table is working with AngularJS 1.4 but if I am trying to used component from AngularJS 1.5 data is not display in table.
Anyone has sample example. I am not able to see data if i change to component.

Thanks
Nik

Comment: Can you post your non-working code?

Comment: Hi, Please find here plunk url [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/2UA5WMk4EE23svyTpLOL?p=preview)